# List with people names

Tags: python, list

I am looking for a solution to a problem, I am trying to make a list on Python that has a way of making a list with People and a set skill like (John= ForkLift Trained, CDL, Jackhammer, electrician.) Something like that but with like 20 names and every trade that an Organizational Leader Degree can use? Can someone help me?

Comment: It sounds like you actually want a dictionary of lists. We'd need more context to be able to help you though.

Comment: "I am looking for a solution to a problem" -- if you are looking for a solution to a homework problem (which this seems to be) the best way to find one is to write one yourself. Ultimately, there is no other way to learn.

Comment: It's not for my homework. It's for a friend I want to help write it.  with all the stuff I had said above,

Comment: @JoeKing No problem. The answer below by Mor Paz is fairly good. You could consider accepting it. In the US, it is getting close to the end of the fall semester at most universities, and desperate students start posting their homework assignments, with no code shown, hoping that the Stack Overflow genie will grant them a solution. Inadvertently, your question seemed a bit like that.

Answer (score 1):

You did not provide any code here to show us what you tried to solve the problem, also you did not specify how knowledgeable you are in python, so it is a bit hard to understand your background approaching this problem.

Here is a possible solution for your issue: create a dictionary with the names of the different employees, and assign to each key in the dictionary an array with the skills of that employee.

For example:

```
employees = {}
employees['John'] = ["ForkLift Trained", "CDL", "Jackhammer", "electrician"]
employees['Brian'] = ["Computer Scientist", "Programmer"]

print(employees)

for k in employees:
    print('worker: {} has the following skills: {}'.format(k, employees[k]))
```

The formatting of the print function can obviously be changed as needed, but this is the general idea.

The output for this code will be:

```
{'John': ['ForkLift Trained', 'CDL', 'Jackhammer', 'electrician'], 'Brian': ['Computer Scientist', 'Programmer']}
worker: John has the following skills: ['ForkLift Trained', 'CDL', 'Jackhammer', 'electrician']
worker: Brian has the following skills: ['Computer Scientist', 'Programmer']
```

Again this is only a rough idea, the problem you described is quite general and can be solved in many different ways unless you provide more information.

**Edit:** the print function for the separate name and skills of each employee is:

```
for k in employees:
    print('worker: {} has the following skills: {}'.format(k, employees[k]))
```

This function will work in printing a single worker or a 1000 workers if enough were loaded inside the dictionary (which was declared using `employees ={}`).
Every employee will have his own seperate line of output.

In order to print the name of an employee with his different skills each in a different line it is possible to use something like this:

```
for k in employees:
    print('{} has the following skills:'.format(k))
    for i in employees[k]:
        print(i)
    print()
```

and the output will be:

```
John has the following skills:
ForkLift Trained
CDL
Jackhammer
electrician

Brian has the following skills:
Computer Scientist
Programmer
```

Comment: My friend is getting a degree in Organizational Leadership. And they have to study Computer Science and have to study Python. I know very little about how to write python. But how would  I get multiple names, Brian and John in a list type?            
                                                                
                                                         print ('worker: {} has the following skills: {}'.format(k, employees[k]))

Comment: It would be mostly the same as how I did it here, but if you have a pre-made list of names and skills (for example, in a file or in an excel sheet) then it is possible to load the data into python and load all of the information into a format similar to what I showed here using a loop.

Comment: If you need the print function to output the data in a specific way then if you show me an example format I can help build that correct print output

Comment: oh ok so like I said I have very little use of python so the command so for john, brian, Jason ----------------------------- print ("for x in Jason") like that in a loop

Comment: look at my edits and let me know if this is what you were looking for